# When arriving to the Schengen area I told the immigration officer I'm staying for a month. Would it be an issue if I stayed for a longer time?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, netherlands, russian-citizens

I have 90/360 multi visa in the Netherlands. I arrived to learn English in a month course, but course was postponed for a week. I told to immigration officer in the airport that I would stay for a month. Now I see that I need to stay here for one more week because of postponement of the training. Do I have to tell the immigration office about the situation? Do I have to register at the nearest police station office?

Comment: Today I went to Vreemdelingenpolitie (Johan Huizingalaan 757 Amsterdam 1066 VH). They work from 8 to 11 a.m., and it is important, because it's very hard to find them (I was late yesterday), so I advise you to go there in advance.
They told me that I can be in Amsterdam for 90(!) days and put a stamp in my passport.

Answer (score 5):

As long as your visa is still valid you are allowed to be in the Netherlands. So shouldn't get in to trouble over an extra week, just don't exceed those 90 days.
Also, your answer to the airport official probably isn't even registered anywhere. They ask random these kind of questions to make an assessment of the person in front of them, not because they want to know the answer...

But if you stay once your visa expired you will likely get problems, especially when they check your papers when you are going back home.

Answer (score 1):

As Avee said, the questioning by immigrations isn't generally recorded unless something suspicious is found and it gets extended into a police investigation (at which point you'd have been taken apart into an interrogation room at the very least).
When in doubt about your visa status, do visit a police station and ask. They can help you either clear things up or direct you to someone who can.
Your visa is good for 90 days ("multi" I guess means multiple entry visa?), so you're good as long as you don't stay more than 90 days in the country (or indeed the Schengen area). You've been 30 days, need to stay another 7, that's less than 90, so unless you have in the past spent more than 53 days already since the visa became active, or unless the 7 days would mean you're overstaying the last date the visa is valid, there should be no problem.

Comment: Police? I thought that would be [IND](http://www.ind.nl/en/Pages/Default.aspx)

Comment: IND yes, police might be easier to get to though, as IND has far less offices and they're not clearly marked (might even be there's only the headquarters in the Hague/Rijswijk which is part of the ministry of Justice building, I am Dutch and have never seen any office of them marked anywhere in the country). They also have a page about short term registration (not visa application, but arrival registration) procedures on their website (Dutch only) https://www.politie.nl/melden/kort-verblijf-vreemdelingen.html

Comment: They have offices but I believe fewer than some years ago (the one I once went to in the Hague does not exist anymore): http://www.ind.nl/contact/adressen/Pages/default.aspx I suppose contacting the police cannot hurt, I have always found them particularly helpful compared to other police forces I know elsewhere in the world.